# error in google app script while setting a formula in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to set up a date formula using an if formula. The logical argument should be, if the next cell in same row is filled, return true, else return false. However I receive following error "Missing ) after argument list. (line 29, file "Code")"

```
ss.getRange(rrCell).setFormula("=IF("+ temp +"="","", now())");
*/ss is spreadhseet identifier, temp = 'G' + activeCell.getRow();
```

Error : Missing ) after argument list. (line 29, file "Code")

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your issue. (Maybe post more of your code.)
However maybe fixing the below will fix your issue:

I changed "" to ''. What you were doing before is adding "=" and then having a syntax error by having "" following without another "+" symbol. (Terrible explanation... It's friday and I have 15 minutes before my weekend starts. :D)

```
ss.getRange(rrCell).setFormula("=IF("+ temp +"='','', now())");
```

Comment: with this it takes formula successfully, but the formula itself throws error as it wants double qoutes to identify blank cells and not single qoutes.

Comment: eliminated the double qoute problem by using the len() function